# extrovert vs extroverted (as adjective, have different usage?)

Tags: word-usage

as per some of dictionaries, extrovert can be used as both noun and adjective, also, the 'extroverted' is used as adjective.

any difference between the usage of 'extroverted' and 'extrovert' when used as adjective?

Comment: Note that some people (particularly psychologists) prefer the original spelling 'extr**a**vert'.

Comment: How do you know the original spelling is 'extr**a**vert?

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/extrovert) -- Oxford Dictionaries online -- explains, “The original spelling extravert is now rare in general use but is found in technical use in psychology.” “Extraversion” is more common in books than “extroversion,” perhaps because of its prevalence in technical literature.

Comment: I have never heard extravert used as an adjective. Do you have an example of it in use?

Comment: The Introvert and Extravert Elderly. Your personality, introvert or extravert?

Comment: I'm struggling to see these examples as adjectives, but maybe that's just me being obtuse.

Comment: the remaining 25 percent showed extravert tendencies

Comment: Again, not seeing it as an adjective here. "extravert tendencies" is just "tendencies of an extravert", no?

Comment: no in my point of view. tendencies (plural and focused subject here) are modified by extravet which looks to me 'adjective' just modifying the noun: tendencies. If it's used as nouns, then I would form the phrase like: extroverts' tendencies